# How do I split a numerical query result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pulling an id number from a database where it is stored as 12345

When I display it on my page (php), I'd like to have it show up as 1-2345

Can I do this without using Javascript? If so, how?

Thanks!

ETA: it's part of a loop of data that is pulled dynamically, so the number is always different. I need to be able to tell it to put a dash after the first number. It's not necessarily 1-2345; it's more X-XXXX (where X is a random number).

Comment: So you want the integer `12345` to be displayed as a string, looking like `1-2345`

Comment: If you post your code we can try to help you.

Comment: What if there are more than 5 digits? Should it be XX-XXXX or X-XXXXX? What if there are more than 8?

Comment: @raina77ow if the OP is pulling out a different ID that is not `12345` why would she wish to `echo `'1-2345';`?

Comment: Will `substr_replace($orig, '-', 1, 0)` do the trick? )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the following in MySQL:

```
select
  concat(left(yourCol, 1), 
         '-', 
         right(yourcol, length(yourCol)-1)) YourValue
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf4fed/1)

This implements the following MySQL functions:

- [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [LEFT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)
- [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)
- [LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

Or you can use `SUBSTR` instead of `RIGHT` and `LENGTH`:

```
select
  concat(left(yourCol, 1), 
         '-', 
         substr(yourcol, 2)) YourValue
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf4fed/4)

- [SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

Comment: While it's cool to do this in SQL, I wonder shouldn't it be the responsibility of View. )

Comment: Yes. This, to me, is display-related logic. Plus there's a good chance that the query supplying this data is abstracted away by an ORM (or at least I hope it is). Further, it's not abundantly clear to a non-SQL expert looking at this what it does.

Comment: @raina77ow Typically when you want data displayed a specific way, you would do it in the presentation layer.  I am showing how this is possible in SQL.

Comment: Wow. That is seriously godly. I hadn't the first idea one could use concatenation inside of SQL. Amazing! +1 upvote for you for teaching me something.

Comment: substr(yourcol, 2) is far more efficient than the whole right, length thing...

Answer (score 4):

In PHP

```
$id = (str)$dbVal;
$str = $id[0]."-".substr($id, 1, strlen($id) - 1);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers don't address *where* to put your code, and why. Inserting a dash after the first digit is display-related logic, and display-related logic belongs in the template. It certainly doesn't belong in the database layer. You could put the actual code right alongside the HTML, but that would be a) probably not very intent-revealing and b) not very reusable.

For the best separation of concerns, I would first define a "helper" function like this, in its own file:

```
function insert_dash_after_first_number($value)
{
  return str_replace($value[0], $value[0].'-', $value);
}
```

Then, in your template, you can do this (granted you included the helper file):

```
<?php echo insert_dash_after_first_number('12345'); ?>
```

Hopefully you can see that separating things in this way would make it pretty clear to others and your future self what's going on. You can just look at the function name and see "oh, this inserts a dash after the first number". You don't have to look at any code and think about what it might do.

Comment: it makes sense to create a function for this, @jason - thank you. I suppose where I'm struggling is that my results are pulled in from a query, split into something like $row['number_id'] along with other tabular data (and while I despise using tables, if it's tabular data I have limited options). I will work on this one and thank you for helping me think this through farther than just an answer that will work, to get to an answer that will work well.

Comment: @MelanieSumnerSmith I was hoping to communicate the principle of separating display logic from business/domain logic. I don't care much about having my answer selected or anything, but I do hope you learn about separation of concerns. Here's an article that describes that a little bit. http://tebros.com/2010/02/separate-display-from-logic/

Comment: Sounds like you're having a separate problem now. Create a separate question, and feel free to link to it, and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = "12345";
echo $var[0] . "-" . substr($var,1);
```

This should work for values of any length.

Answer (score 3):

First, use your `SELECT` MySQL command to find your ID number. 
Let's say `$string` is actually the 'stringified' version of the ID.

```
$string = "12345"; 
$string = str_replace($string[0], $string[0] . "-", $string); 
echo $string;
```

Comment: Nice - the `str_replace` method is probably the most concise way out of all the answers I've seen so far. I've borrowed heavily from that in my answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Actually, no, `substr_replace` is the most relevant here (as it's the string equivalent of `array_splice`).

Comment: @raina77ow, actually, I was going to go for `substr_replace`, but I wanted the OP to see what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $string1 = substr($id, 0,1);
 $string2 = substr($id, 1, strlen($id));
```